# Vote counter to show received votes

Tags: feature-request

There is a vote counter showing the votes we casted as follows

[image]

It will be very helpful if a vote counter is there which shows the **votes I received (Votes against my account)** which is similar to this one **(but show both up and down in day and week)**.

#### In my point of view, let me explain how it will be helpful

I can see the number of votes I received in the day ( or even in the week).

Comparing the downvotes with upvotes, I can check whether I can improve my post, what are all the mistakes I have done and so on.

If the number of downvotes is very low, then leave it. If it is very high, we can analyse it.

So, it will be helpful for self analysis and improvement.

Comment: How is this any different from going to `/reputation`? It gives you this information and more.

Comment: yes. But in the rep tab, we have to pick the downvotes from a wide range of rep changes like upvote, downvote, downvoted, accepted, etc. and we have to choose downvote only. When I would like to see the downvote I received in a week, it is very difficult. and if I want to view the same for all time, it is very very difficult to count from rep tab. @Oded

Comment: I didn't say rep tab. I said `/reputation`. Like so: https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation (some parsing may be required)

Comment: that looks good. but in that I have to execute some regex test and script to filter the downvotes like `var a=document.body.textContent.match(/\(\-2\)/g);
a.length;`. Looks good but when it comes to month or week, it will be helpful if a counter is there. @Oded